# How to get rid of freestyle faces?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle

So here's whats happening. I marked all of my faces as freestyle. If I press 'clear freestyle face' the annoying green line over everything stays. Is there something I'm doing wrong or is it something different to freestyle?

Image:

[image: Green lines]

Comment: Is everything selected (A) when you click clear freestyle?

Comment: @gandalf3 yes, I just unselected everything so you could see the lines

Comment: That *should* make the green highlights go away.. Is it possible you could upload a .blend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me you marked freestyle edges, not faces. The green lines are the edge marks.

To clear the marks go to `Edit Mode`, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to bring up the Edges menu and select `Clear Freestyle Edge`.

[image: Clear Freestyle Edge]